# How do I sign out of all Gmail sessions without access to a computer?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

I know the method to do sign out from all devices on a computer. (Go to Gmail page, in bottom right, click **Details**, and click **Sign out all other web sessions**)

How do I do this if I don't have computer and just have my phone?

Comment: Mobile browsers can be instructed to load the desktop version of a certain site; from there you can do whatever you can do on a computer.

Comment: If the question is about using the site on a mobile (as in a mobile browser), then it's not off-topic IMO. But if it's regarding the mobile app then it is. @AlE.

Comment: I'm just trying to get you to where you have the best shot of getting the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

This option is only available using a browser as documented in the 'Sign out of all sessions' of [this article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?hl=en).

I just tested and this option can be found in a mobile browser. I used Chrome on my Android phone.

Start by going to mail.google.com. Select the menu icon on the left, scroll to the bottom, choose the Desktop link, then follow the same steps you would use from your computer.